# Sort varchar datatype with numeric characters in sqlite3-- Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a varchar column that needs to be sorted by the number included in it. The data is similar to:

```
L1,L10,L11,L12,L2,L20,L21
```

I want the output like this where the value is sorted by the number.

```
L1,L2,L10,L11,L12,L20,L21
```

Comment: has every varchar only one letter and is it always a L ?

Comment: no,it's can be another letter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split your table into two columns. 
One for the "alphabetical" part and one for the numeric part.
Then you could easily sort it by using a select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_conditions ORDER BY numeric_column ASC;
```

Comment: the column is UK's postcode. so I can't split my table into two columns.